# Code Explanation of functions return statement

Tags: javascript

Im currently learning javascript... there was this particular challenge where I cant figure out why is the output as is.. so here is the code:

```
function addBinary(a,b) {

    var sum = a + b;
    var res= "";
    while(sum > 0) {
        res = sum % 2 + res;
        sum = Math.floor(sum/2);
    }
    return res;

}
alert(addBinary(1,2));
```

//output is 11

what I dont understand in this addBinary function is why `res = sum % 2 + res;` an empty string after first iteration === 1.

I understand the logic behind modulo operator and 3%2 = 1;

but what I dont get is the `+ res` in the `res = sum % 2 + res;` expression.

Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what I dont get is the + res in the res = sum % 2 + res; expression.

Okay so after the first iteration, the first 1 gets stored in `res`:

```
 res = 1 + "" /*res*/
```

as `res` was an empty string before, the `+` concatenates both as strings, so `res` contains `"1"` now. Now the loop proceeds as one 1 is still needed, so at the next iteration, `sum % 2` is again `1` and the line is:

```
 res = 1 + "1" /*res*/
```

so we end up at the result `"11"`

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, now it makes much more sense!! what I didn't know was the syntax of this expression  'sum % 2 + res;'

but now I perfectly understand.. and of course when you concatenate string and num its string..

thanks again Jonas ;)

Answer (score 0):

It take either `0` or `1` from the remainder operator and the previous collected values and assigns it to `res`.

```
       1       10  -> 110
res = sum % 2 + res;
```